# How to show UIActivityIndicator on UITableView in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have the 100 tableviewcells for displaying the product's information.
I want to show the UIActivityIndicator on UITableView when loading the data from the server.
The tableviewcell was set up with custom(2 UIImages and 3 UILabels).
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume we can split your task into 2 stages:

- Time until a json (or xml) data arrives.

At this point you don't have anything to show. So all you can is to show one big activity indicator in the center of the screen (or whatever design you have). It could be something like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

- Json has arrived.

At this point it's good to show users at least something: you know the amount of elements and some texts. But you don't have images (I suppose you get only URL's in the first response).

You may show some nice placeholders and wait until actual images arrive. Sometimes people put [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/) in a center of each image on the screen which is being loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but  the UIView that shows the loading data from the site, can not be loaded on tableview screen in my code and xCode said to me some errors as above. Please help my code.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. You should add an activity indicator view on a superview of your table view instead of table view itself. If you use UITableViewController, I would recommend to switch to UIViewController.